# android callback fails in fragment fails cannot be cast to android.content.Context

Tags: android, callback, android-fragments

I have a callback class gaGPS which requires I think is a context which works fine in a normal activity but when I use in a Fragment it fails

here is my interface class

```
Public class gaGPS extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

private gaGPSinterface gpsu;

public interface gaGPSinterface {
    public void locationChanged(Location newloc);
}


public gaGPS(Context c, gaGPSinterface gpsiface) {
    mCallback = gpsiface;
    //mContext = (Context) gpsiface;
    mContext = c;


    locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}
```

snip

I'm launching the Fragment using this FragmentActivity class

```
public class gaDetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gpsfragment);

}
```

here is the gpsfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".gpsfragment" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/gpsTestFragLayout"
    android:name="id.wilsononline.gcadroid.gpsfragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

the following is the Fragment I'm using

```
public class gpsfragment extends Fragment implements gaGPS.gaGPSinterface {

private gaGPS gps;

@Override
public void locationChanged(Location newloc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gpsdetails, container, false);
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gpsText1)).setText("testing fragment");

    Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    gps = new gaGPS(c, (gaGPSinterface) getActivity());

    return rootView;
}
```

}

errors I'm getting are :
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.app.gpsfragment cannot be cast to android.content.Context

more fuller output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.com.test.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at id.wilsononline.gcadroid.gaDetailsActivity.onCreate(gaDetailsActivity.java:12)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.com.test.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.com.test.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.com.test.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.com.test.app.gaDetailsActivity cannot be cast to id.wilsononli
ne.gcadroid.gaGPS$gaGPSinterface
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at com.test.com.test.app.gpsfragment.onCreateView(gpsfragment.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.support.v4.com.test.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.support.v4.com.test.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.support.v4.com.test.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.support.v4.com.test.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.support.v4.com.test.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3118):        ... 21 more
```

Comment: can we see /res/layout/gpsfragment.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public gaGPS(gaGPSinterface gpsu) {
    this.mContext = (Context) gpsu;
    this.gpsu = gpsu;
    // ...
}
```

Here, you're trying to cast `gpsu` to a `Context`. It's is not one; it's a `Fragment`. You should pass the `Context` and `gaGPSinterface` separately:

```
public gaGPS(Context c, gaGPSinterface gpsu) {
    this.mContext = c;
    this.gpsu = gpsu;
    // ...
}
```

Then, call it using `.getActivity()` (which returns an `Activity`, a subclass of `Context`) from the `Fragment`:

```
gps = new gaGPS(getActivity(), this);
```

Comment: ok I'll give it a try but my first instinct is that this will fail too as I'm getting the cast error in the Fragment not the interface class

Comment: Nope: "`at com.test.app.gaGPS.<init>(gaGPS.java:55)`" (from your stack trace). The `Fragment` can't inflate because that exception (thrown as part of its execution) exists.

Comment: You're deviating from the code I've provided and doing an odd cast. `gps = new gaGPS(c, (gaGPSinterface) getActivity());` should be `gps = new gaGPS(getActivity(), this);`.

Comment: I wonder if you can explain why it used to work in a normal activity?

Comment: Yes; `Activity` extends `Context`, so the casting would work. `Fragment` does not, so you can't cast it in that way.